# try/catch in constructor for incorrect amount of variables

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I'm reading a file from the Client class, passing it to the Service constructor. I'm using StringTockenizer to parse the 1 line of String passed. The valid lines should have exactly 5 items in it. If the line has more or less than 5 items, it should be considered invalid and ignored.

If the constructor throws the exception, I want it to be handled later in the Client class.
The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to properly read the file, ignore the invalid lines, then continue reading until the end of the file. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;   //allows use of StringTockenizer
 import java.util.ArrayList;   //allows use of ArrayList
 import java.io.Serializable;   //allows use of Serializable

 public class MailingLabel implements Serializable
 {   //start class
   public String name, address, city, state, zipCode;

  public MailingLabel(String input) throws IllegalMailingLabelException  
      //accepts String parameter from Client
  {   //start constructor
  int count = 0;
  String extra;   //used to hold extra tokens from invalid lines
  StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(info, ",");

  name = token.nextToken();   //1st token in string
  count++;
  address = token.nextToken();   //2nd token in string
  count++;
  city = token.nextToken();   //3rd token in string
  count++;
  state = token.nextToken();   //4th token in string
  count++;
  zipCode = token.nextToken();   //5th token in string
  count++;   //count should equal 5
   extra = token.nextToken();   //holds extra tokens
   count++;

  if (count > 5)
     throw new IllegalMailingLabelException("Exactly 5 fields are required");
```

If the line of data has 6 tokens in it, the error is successfully thrown, but it's now throwing an error for the valid lines (because the line doesn't contain a 6th token). I don't want to write another exception for that. 
               }   //end constructor

below is my constructed Exception

```
  public class IllegalMailingLabelException extends NoSuchFieldException 
 {   //start class
 public IllegalMailingLabelException(String message)
 {   //start constructor
  super( message );
  }   //end constructor
  }   //end class
```

//below is client

```
 import java.io.*;   //allows use of BufferedReader & ObjectOutputStream
 import java.util.*;   //allows use of ArrayList

 public class Client1
 {   //start class

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{   //start main  
  String input;   //holds each line read from file

  try    
  {   //start try, opens and reads the file       
     BufferedReader bufIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("testData.txt")));
```

Example data in testData.txt is:
1,2,3,4,5,6    //this should be invalid data
1,2,3,4   //this should be invalid data as well
1,2,3,4,5    //this is valid data

```
     System.out.println("Beginning to read file");

     while ( (info = bufIn.readLine()) != null)
     {   //start while
        try
        {   //start try to create new MailingLabel Object
           MailingLabel label = new MailingLabel(input);                  
        }  //end try
        catch(IllegalMailingLabelException e)
       {   //start catch, if object not created 
                    //(handles the exception thrown by service)
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
                        //prints error message from service constructor
        }   //end catch

     }   //end while
     System.out.println("Finshed reading file");
     bufIn.close();   //closes the file
  }   //end try

  catch (FileNotFoundException e)   //if file isn't found
  {   //start catch
     System.out.println("File not found");
  }   //end catch
 }   //end main
 }   //end class
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: read five tokens, then check via `hasMoreTokens`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parser method doesn't call [`token.hasMoreTokens()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreTokens--) to actually check if the next token exists - might want to do that after reading the fifth field.

Alternately, just call [`input.split(",")`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) and get the fields as an array - then validating the number of fields is simple.